# Changed router, now connections do not work anymore

Tags: mysql, apache, connection-timeout

i yet always had a normal router with WLAN access, and i had my own webserver, running over port 2570, a mysql database on port 3306, and a no-ip client that updated my ip to my hostname example-domain.com!

Now i got a new router, as i wanted 80mbit speed instead of 20mbit, and now after the installation, everything has changed!

Now, i forwarded all ports again, 3306, 53, and 2570, and then after restarting apache servers, mysql servers, PC, and router, i can not connect to my website anymore.

MySQL tells me 10060 error (not allowed to access), i checked if the ports are working with the portforward software, and they all are working!

Then if i enter example-domain.com:2570, it just times out, (the PC i am connecting from, is the server itselfe), if i use 10.0.0.2:2570, it works if its only plain html, and no mysql is involved, and if i do the same from my mobile phone, using the 3G internet connection (disconnected from WLAN), i can even connect from example-domain.com:2570( as long as default document does not involve any mysql connections)!

So, what is this? How can it be, that i was able to connect at any time before i changed my router, and now i can only reach my domain if i am not in the same network, AND, that i can only connect over my LAN-IP (10.0.0.2), IF i am connect to wlan? It worked before too, now it does not, and i dont want to use the ip to connect to my website when i use WLAN...

I heard something about proxys? and that you cannot connect over an external ip, if the PC you are connecting from, has the sams IP? But why did it work before then?

I hope someone can help me here, because i really do not know what to do..